# How to get the "System locale" setting on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, windows-phone

Under Settings on your phone you can set the

- "Display language" (retrieved via `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`),
- "Region Format" (retrieved via `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`), and
- "System locale", retrieved via **?**

Does anyone know how to retrieve the value set for "System locale"?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName
```

Source: http://www.ginktage.com/2011/06/retreive-the-country-name-in-windows-phone-7/

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work - it returns the "Region Format".

Comment: You are indeed right, sorry about that. The same basic question was asked on MSDN but never received an answer, and I can't find any other hints so I'd be tempted to say you can't... May I ask why you need to get the system locale? There may be other solutions to your overall problem...

Comment: No worries.  I need to provide different behavior in my app (connect to different servers) depending on which locale they have selected. I'm going with "Region format", because I can't find a way to detect the "System locale".